# Transform list of instances into list of instance attributes

Tags: python, list, instance

I have a list of instances, and I need to extract from that list a certain attribute of each of the instances, which will form a new list. I'm somewhat new to Python, and the only way I can solve this makes use of the exec() function, which obviously makes it a horrible solution. Does anybody know of a better way?

My current function is:

```
def attributelist(list, attribute):
    "Inputs a list of instances and returns a list of a certain attribute of those instances"
    output = []
    for instance in list:
        exec("output.append(instance." + attribute + ")")
    return output
```

For example, working with the class 'my_class' with attribute 'name':

```
instances = []
for i in range(10):
    instances.append(my_class(i))

attributelist(instances, 'name')
Out: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `getattr` instead of using `exec`:

```
output.append(getattr(instance, attribute))
```

You could also simplify your function by using generators:

```
def attributelist(list_, attribute):
    "Inputs a list of instances and returns a list of a certain attribute of those instances"
    return [getattr(i, attribute) for i in list_]
```

You could leave off the square braces if you don't mind getting an iterator instead of a `list`. (You might need parentheses to do so.)

Comment: I would rename `list`. It shadows the builtin `list` function.

Comment: Good catch. I copy/pasted from OP's code and didn't notice. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`attrgetter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) with `map`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

map(attrgetter('foo'), iterable)
```

`attrgetter('foo')` creates a function that returns the `foo` attribute of whatever argument you call it with. Plus, it's implemented in C and will be faster than `getattr()` and a list comprehension.

If you're using Python 3, `map` won't return a list, so you'll have to pass it through `list()` to get one.